# What is the type of conservation in which seed banks are an example?

Tags: evolution, homework, conservation-biology

Firstly I think this question is quite ambiguous (I did not come up with it) so sorry.

I have only come across 4 'types' of conservation: environmental, animal, marine, and human conservation.

I am aware that animal conservation includes their habitats, so perhaps keeping seed banks is a way of preserving habitats.

I may generally say that seed banks are a way of preserving biodiversity but I don't know if 'biodiversity conservation' is even a thing.

Comment: I don' t really get what your "types" are referring to (do you have a reference to these specific four types?) and they are clearly not covering all cases in conservation biology. They are also not mutually exklusive, and can overlap. Also, by "*seed bank*"I assume that you are referring to human conservation of seeds (as genetic material, see eg the [Svalbard Global Seed Vault](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard_Global_Seed_Vault)) and not the soil seed bank that some species has.

Comment: @Mesentery could you expand?

Comment: I agree with @fileunderwater. The "types" you list are unclear. The question is based upon a series of issues of terminology and semantics and therefore cannot be answered. Anyone could just say random things like "agriculture conservation", "plant conservation", "economic conservation", "field conservation", "forest conservation", "private-sector conservation", etc... and there is no way to judge what would make sense or not. I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Remi.b I am simply rewriting the question that has been set as homework. Any ambiguity is therefore not at all down to me. Part of the reason I asked here is because I did not really understand the question. I also "shared my previous  attempts" at the question and therefore have met the question asking guidelines.

Comment: @BenHughes Is there a certain book your homework/lectures is based on? Or did you get any definitions during the lesions regarding the terms you used in the question?

Comment: @Marzipanherz no it was amongst a bunch of past paper questions he set us

Comment: @BenHughes You might want to link to this series of paper. Maybe one of them attempt to do this kind of categorization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seed banks are a part of "plant conservation" efforts which is missing from your list.

Comment: IMO the question makes no sense and an answer to a senseless question cannot make any sense (unless it starts by redefining the question). -1

Comment: I do see your point.  But, one of the problems that I've seen on one other SE site is that questions go unanswered because they are somehow viewed as unworthy.  I choose to answer if it takes less energy than many of the comments. IMO.